# DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_NO_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE'

Tags: exe, appx, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter, makeappx

I want to convert an .exe file using the DesktopAppConverter tool, using this command

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer 'D:\Projects\Finance Workspace\New folder\deploy\exe only\pac
kages\bundles\Fun Money-1.0.exe' -Destination 'D:\Projects\Finance Workspace\New folder\deploy\exe only\packages\bundles
\appX' -PackageName "Funmoney" -Publisher "CN=Derbyware" -Version 1.0.0.0 -MakeAppx
```

I get this error

> DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_NO_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE': No expanded
>   base images were found at 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images'.
>   Please run with -Setup to expand a new base image. At line:1 char:1

How Can I fix this please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an app you need to download a Docker base image of Win10, with the same build number as your machine has.

- [Details on what to download and how to configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#set-a-few-things-up-apps-with-installers-only)

Also, If you have problems with the Microsoft DAC you [try this new converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#set-a-few-things-up-apps-with-installers-only), it is much easier to use, it has a GUI (no command line), built-in support for digital signing and allows you to customize the list of files that get inside your AppX.

Also, you can generate AppX packages for applications which do not (cannot) install silently.

It runs on Windows 7 too, not just Windows 10 (*recommended*).

Comment: Yes I discovered that and I have fix it. Thanks